# Exporting excel error : File you are trying to open FileName is in different format than specified extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, visual-studio-2008

I have used following code to export data from dataset to excel file:

```
 public void ExportRecords(System.Data.DataTable dt, String fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string path = AllinAudio_Temp;
                string timestamp = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);
                timestamp = timestamp.Replace(" ", "");
                timestamp = timestamp.Replace("/", "");
                timestamp = timestamp.Replace(":", "");
                fileName = fileName.Replace(" ", "");

                string filename = path + @"\" + timestamp + "_" + fileName + ".xls";
                CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter.Workbook book = new CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter.Workbook();

                //// Add a Worksheet with some data
                CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter.Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
                WorksheetStyle style = book.Styles.Add("HeaderStyle");
                style.Font.Bold = true;
                WorksheetStyle style1 = book.Styles.Add("HeaderStyle1");
                style1.Font.Bold = true;
                style1.Font.Color = "Red";

                WorksheetRow row;// = sheet.Table.Rows.Add();

                row = sheet.Table.Rows.Add();
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Cells.Add(new WorksheetCell(column.ColumnName, "HeaderStyle"));
                }




                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    row = sheet.Table.Rows.Add();

                    for (int l = 0; l < dt.Columns.Count; l++)
                    {
                        row.Cells.Add(dt.Rows[i][l].ToString());


                    }


                }

                book.Save(filename);
                Response.ContentType = "text/excel";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + timestamp + "_" + fileName + ".xls");
                Response.TransmitFile(filename);
                Response.End();


            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

When the file gets exported and we try to open it, it gives me message:

[image]

I want the file in xls format only and i am also exxporting it in xls format.

But why this kind of error comes when i try to open it.

**When i tried with XLSX**

[image]

Comment: this might be useful for you

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948615

Answer (score 2):

The biggest hint is in the name of the component you're using to create the files.  `ExcelXmlWriter` appears to write files in the Excel XML format, which should have the file extension `XML`.  When you use the `XLS` extension, Excel is expecting the content to be in the older format.  When it fails to open the file as a classic Excel file it tries the alternatives, finds that the Excel XML works and warns you of the problem.

Solution: change your output code to use the file extension `XML` instead of `XLS`.

(Not XLSX as previously stated.)

Comment: sir, same problem occured when i tried it with xlsx, plz see my edit

Comment: sir, what extension it requires?

Comment: but , iwant to see it as excel file

Comment: Then you'll have to either associate Excel with `XML` files, change the registry to get rid of the message, or live with the message.  `XML` _is_ the correct extension for this format apparently.

Answer (score 1):

try this function

```
 public static void ExportToExcelOnece(DataSet dsExcel, string ExcelFilePath)
    {

        if (dsExcel == null || dsExcel.Tables.Count == 0)
            throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Null or empty input table!\n");

        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
        Excel.Worksheet newWorksheet;
        Excel.Worksheet objSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];

        for (int m = 0; m <= dsExcel.Tables.Count - 1; m++)
        {
            newWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.Worksheets.Add(objSheet, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            newWorksheet.Name = dsExcel.Tables[m].TableName;

            // column headings
            for (int i = 0; i < dsExcel.Tables[m].Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                newWorksheet.Cells[1, (i + 1)] = dsExcel.Tables[m].Columns[i].ColumnName;
            }

            // rows
            for (int i = 0; i < dsExcel.Tables[m].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dsExcel.Tables[m].Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    newWorksheet.Cells[(i + 2), (j + 1)] = dsExcel.Tables[m].Rows[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        ((Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[1]).Activate();

        objSheet.Delete();
        objSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets["Sheet2"];
        objSheet.Delete();
        objSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets["Sheet3"];
        objSheet.Delete();

        // check fielpath
        if (ExcelFilePath != null && ExcelFilePath != "")
        {
            try
            {
                excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(ExcelFilePath);
                excelApp.Quit();
                MessageBox.Show("Excel file saved!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Excel file could not be saved! Check filepath.\n"
                    + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else    // no filepath is given
        {
            excelApp.Visible = true;
        }


        //Quit the Application.
        excelApp.Quit();

    }
```

Comment: While this will indeed create an `XLS` or `XLSX` file, it will only do so if Excel is installed on the system.  The advantage of the various XL file writers is that they don't require you to have Excel installed.